# Change ListViewItem text color

Tags: wpf

I am currently creating ListViewItems programatically like so:

```
ListView.Items.Add(New With {Key .Name = ItemName, Key .DateCreated = ItemDateCreated, Key .Description = ItemDescription})
```

I have found no way of changing the color of the item, as I have not found a way of creating a `ListViewItem` with sub items in any other way than this one.

Is it possible to change the color of the item's text (or background if not possible), while still being able to have subitems?

EDIT - This is my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" Opacity="0.75">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="ListViewGridView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="155" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date Created" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateCreated}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you set the foreground property in the ItemTemplate your ListView is using? Seeing your XAML would be very useful here

Comment: I added the ListView XAML.

Comment: Hopefully my answer actually answered your question, let me know if you were looking for more/different information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following sample will set the first column's text to green. On a side note, you should probably wrap your "Name", "Date Created" and "Description" fields into an actual object and use it to create your ListViewItem with subitems instead of trying to create a new weakly typed object each time (I did this and attached the code if you are interested, obviously you can use any data type for members (not just string) but I was coding quickly).

Information on DataTemplates: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" Opacity="0.75">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="ListViewGridView">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="155">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date Created" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateCreated}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

C#:

```
// In method somewhere, won't work otherwise
ListView.Items.Add(new DataClass("Bob", "12/04/2013", "Person", Color.Green));

public class DataClass
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String DateCreated { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public SolidBrushColor { get; set; }
    public DataClass (string Name, String Date, String Desc, SolidBrushColor textColor)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.DateCreated = Date;
        Description = Desc;
        Color = textColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I wasn't clear enough. What I want to do is be able to set the color of the text _inside the C# code_, not in the XAML. Though the `DataClass` is a useful thing to take in mind. Also, the link does not work for me...

Comment: Nevermind, I have found the answer. Just had to replace `Foreground="Green"` with `Foreground="{Binding Color}"`, and edit code accordingly. Could you add that to your answer? If not, I'll post my own answer.

Comment: Changed my code to reflect your changes, glad you found the solution you were looking for.

Comment: Note that you may want to consider using a DataTrigger to set your colors rather than doing so programmatically. UI specific logic (colors, visibility, etc.) should generally be in the markup when using WPF.